# How do I insert text at specific line numbers in a text file?

Tags: windows

I need to insert text (specifically the FormFeed character, ASCII value 12 or 0xC) every 66 lines in a text file on a Windows box. Is there a built-in tool that can accomplish this?

Comment: have you considered using windows batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be done easily enough with PowerShell, JScript, or VBScript. But if you want to stay within the batch world, then you will need some type of non-standard utility or complicated batch program.

Using a [hybrid JScript/batch utility called REPL.BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4402290/1012053) that performs a regex search and replace on stdin and writes the result to stdout:

```
type "file.txt"|repl "(.*\n){66}" "$&\x0C" mx >"file.txt.new"
move /y "file.txt.new" "file.txt" >nul
```

The above assumes you have REPL.BAT in your current directory, or better yet, somewhere within your path.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow that Powershell is built-in for recent Windows versions, you could do it like this from Powershell:

```
(gc input.txt -raw) -replace '(.*\n){66}', "`$0$([char]0x0c)" > output.txt
```

If you're running from cmd.exe, you would run this like:

```
powershell (gc input.txt -raw) -replace '(.*\n){66}', \"`$0$([char]0x0c)\" > output.txt
```

Note that Powershell will use 'Unicode encoding' when you use `>` redirection. If you want a different encoding you can pipe to `out-file -encoding [oem|default|ascii|utf8]` (more info on encodings [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx), under the -Encoding heading).

e.g.:

```
(gc input.txt -raw) -replace '(.*\n){66}', "`$0$([char]0x0c)" | out-file -encoding utf8
```